# Powershell convert string to date

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am putting together some custom monitoring solutions and the logs include different date/time entries. Trying to parse the date/time (text value) from the log and convert into a date value so that I can compare with others or with system date. I have used the following in the past, but am having trouble changing to allow for single digit DD value and for 12 hour clock value.

```
$line = "=== 2018-01-07 03:30:25,889 [ng)'] INFO"

$dateTimeString = [regex]::Matches($line, '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)')[0].Groups[1].Value

$provider = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo "en-US"

$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateTimeString, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', $provider)
```

But need to convert the following.

$line = "Error - Jan 7, 2018 2:13:19 AM EST - Warning"

I'm sure the parseexact will be:
$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateTimeString, 'MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt', provider)

But I am having trouble parsing the text into these values using the Matches function.

Edit:
After utilizing Bill's suggestion, when assigning variable explicitly, it works. However when I spool Get-Content to the variable it doesn't.

```
$line = Get-Content $SBWebPath | Select-String $SBError -casesensitive |select -last 1
Write-Output $line
$line | Select-String '^####<(\S+ \S+, \S+ \S+ \S+) \S+> <Warning>' | ForEach-Object {
$dateTime = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [DateTime]
}
$dateTime
```

Output:

```
####<Dec 7, 2017 5:17:26 AM EST> <Warning> <HTTP>
```

Edit2:

As described by Bill, the $line was being converted into an array so the ForEach-Object was not able to parse the array. By Adding | Out-String to the end of the line, it was then able to parse it as a string.

Final Code that works:

```
$line = Get-Content $SBWebPath | Select-String $SBError -casesensitive | Select -last 1 | Out-String
Write-Output $line
$line | Select-String '^####<(\S+ \S+, \S+ \S+ \S+) \S+> <Warning>' | ForEach-Object {
$dateTime = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [DateTime]
}
$dateTime
```

Cheers to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one (fairly short) way:

```
$line = "Error - Jan 7, 2018 2:13:19 AM EST - Warning"
$line | Select-String '^Error - (\S+ \S+, \S+ \S+ \S+) \S+ -' | ForEach-Object {
  $dateTime = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [DateTime]
}
$dateTime
```

One caveat for this approach is you lose the time zone information.

To do this for an entire file, you can write something similar to this:

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # $_ here means "current line from input file"
  $_ | Select-String '^Error - (\S+ \S+, \S+ \S+ \S+) \S+ -' | ForEach-Object {
    # $_ here means "current MatchInfo object"
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [DateTime]
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this and it seems to be working great. However now if I don't declare $line explicitly, it is unable to convert. See Edit above.

Comment: If you write `$line = Get-Content file.txt`, The `$line` variable will only contain one line if the file contains a single line; otherwise, it will contain an array. You can use `ForEach-Object` to iterate the output of `Get-Content` regardless of whether it contains a single line or an array. The `$_` means "current item from the pipeline." See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Get-Date command to convert strings to dates avoiding issues around cultural settings or local computer settings.

Referencing example 4 from URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6

```
(Get-Date -Year 2000 -Month 12 -Day 31).DayOfYear
```

I updated the file's modified date using command LastWriteTime.  I parsed the filename to obtain the date and time.

```
$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date -Year $y -Month $m -Day $d -Hour $h -Minute $n -Second $s
```

My code to update modified date for an entire directory of files is as follows.  I've included all of my extra echo statements which I used during the construction of this script.  Hopefully this verbosity helps you understand each step better.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\*.jpg' | ForEach-Object {

    # File Info
    echo $_.FullName
    echo $_.BaseName
    echo $_.BaseName.IndexOf(" . ")
    echo $_.BaseName.SubString(26,17)
    $y = $_.BaseName.SubString(26,4)
    $m = $_.BaseName.SubString(31,2)
    $d = $_.BaseName.SubString(34,2)
    $h = $_.BaseName.SubString(37,2)
    $n = $_.BaseName.SubString(39,2)
    $s = $_.BaseName.SubString(41,2)
    $date = "$y,$m,$d,$h,$n,$s"
    echo $date

    # Modified Date
    echo $_.LastWriteTime

    # Update Modified Date
    $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date -Year $y -Month $m -Day $d -Hour $h -Minute $n -Second $s
    echo $_.LastWriteTime
}
```